# MoveIt only moves one joint

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am facing issues when trying to move more than one joint. I am following the MoveIt tutorial for Python but adding more than one joint, in example:

```
group_variable_values = group.get_current_joint_values()
# shoulder_pan_joint
group_variable_values[0] = 0.0
#shoulder_lift_joint
group_variable_values[1] = 0.0
#elbow_joint
group_variable_values[2] = 0.0
#wrist_1_joint
group_variable_values[3] = 0.0
#wrist_2_joint
group_variable_values[4] = 2.57
#wrist_3_joint
group_variable_values[5] = -3.14
group.set_joint_value_target(group_variable_values)
plan = group.plan()
rospy.sleep(5)
group.execute(plan)
```

I have looked at https://answers.ros.org/question/273732/moveit-move-only-one-joint/ and it seems I am trying to accomplish the same goal but the answer seems to be my current implementation (unless there is an equivalent of `move` in Python and I should not be using `execute`)

It is probably worth noting I am using universal_robot library and the model of UR5. The group which I am modifying is `group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("manipulator")`

As it stands with the above implementation only one joint moves, I would like for all the joints to move. Is there something I am doing wrong in the above?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280574/moveit-only-moves-one-joint/) by [Xylus](https://answers.ros.org/users/33397/xylus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anybody facing this issue: I have fixed it by turning off gui mode in my `.launch` file for rviz. I have no idea why that would introduce joint constraints.

---

Originally posted by [Xylus](https://answers.ros.org/users/33397/xylus/) with karma: 26 on 2018-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1